# How to verify if Number is three digit Decimal in a Table in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

there is a table with numbers and some columns contain decimal numbers
for example 12.234, 45.094.
how can I verify if those numbers are three-digit decimal numbers?

Comment: `new Select(WebElement element)` does not work on every dropdown. Please share url or source code sample.

Comment: new Select(WebElement element) works fine, All I need is how can I verify all the values of Dropdown one by one.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259524/in-selenium-need-to-validate-search-result/70261987#70261987. Instead of testing on `contains` you'll test on `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`.